# How to handle Odata in Redux?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm developing a Ngrx Angular Application.
I would like to know what is the best practice to use when using OData.
For example I need to display a Grid of Users.

I'm using a DevExtreme grid, so I just need to pass the Odata url to the grid and it handles everything.
Should I use also the store?
How?

Thanks a lot

Comment: do you mean this: https://www.odata.org/ ?